# Getting inline JSON to parse

Tags: javascript, html, yui

Are there any tricks to get this inline json object to parse? $a[3] is a mako variable containing a url.

```
<li class="foldernode" yuiConfig='{"type":"TextNode","data":"{&#39;myurl&#39;:&#39;${a[3]}&#39;}"}'>
```

Without the "type" attribute it works:

```
<li class="foldernode" yuiConfig='{"data":"{&#39;myurl&#39;:&#39;${a[3]}&#39;}"}'>
```

I already had to do something hacky and use `&#39;` for single quotes which I then replace with double quotes in javascript. Any general strategies for doing this type of nested quoting would be helpful.

Comment: Why are there even more quotes around `data`'s value? I'd expect it to look something like `'{"type":"TextNode","data":{&#39;myurl&#39;:&#39;${a[3]}&#39;}}'`

Comment: Trial and error. I get a JSON.parse error from YUI when I take them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick I usually use it to write the object in generic JavaScript, call JSON.stringify on it and copy the result. The result I got was `{"type":"TextNode","data":{"myurl":"${a[3]}"}}`.

Comment: +1, JSON always uses double quotes to wrap properties / values. Single quotes aren't valid JSON.